# Unexpected behaviour when firing a apex method

Tags: apex, batch, cpulimit, debug-logs

I have this piece of code:

```java
public static void initTraitementBillingApi() {

    String methodName = 'traitementDPF';
    ObjectUtil.debugLogBegin(CLASSNAME, methodName, '');

    //String periode = PERIODE_ACCEPTATION_KPI;
    String periode = Date.today().addMonths(- 1).month() < 10 ? Date.today().year() + '0' + Date.today().addMonths(- 1).month() : Date.today().year() + '' + Date.today().addMonths(- 1).month();

    String pathKpi = API_ACCEPTATION_KPI;

    Map<String, BAS_Wrapper> mapIdConcatWrapper = new Map<String, BAS_Wrapper> ();
    Map<String, Map<Id, SocieteWrapper>> mapIdAccMapBUWraps = new Map<String, Map<Id, SocieteWrapper>> ();
    Map<String, Map<Id, MagasinWrapper>> mapIdBuMapMagWraps = new Map<String, Map<Id, MagasinWrapper>> ();
    Set<String> setIdCompte = new Set<String> ();
    Map<Id, Decimal> mapIdCompte_distribAmt = new Map<Id, Decimal> ();

    HttpResponse resKpi = SM002_LigneDeFacture.calloutKpi(pathKpi, periode);

    ObjectUtil.debugLog(CLASSNAME, methodName, 'resKpi = ' + resKpi.getBody());

    Integer limitKpi;
    Integer offsetKpi;

    if (resKpi.getStatusCode() == 200) {

        //new ApexDebugLog().createLog(new ApexDebugLog.Information(CLASSNAME, methodName, null, 'callout billing_acceptation_spring_kpi OK'));
        SM002_LigneDeFacture.BAS_kpi_Wrapper basKpi = (SM002_LigneDeFacture.BAS_kpi_Wrapper) JSON.deserialize(resKpi.getBody(), SM002_LigneDeFacture.BAS_kpi_Wrapper.class);

        limitKpi = Integer.valueOf(basKpi.total);
        offsetKpi = 0;
        //String pathA = PATH + API_ACCEPTATION;
        String pathA = API_ACCEPTATION;

        HttpResponse res = SM002_LigneDeFacture.calloutBillingApi(pathA, limitKpi, offsetKpi, periode);

        if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {

            new ApexDebugLog().createLog(new ApexDebugLog.Information(CLASSNAME, methodName, 'Callout vers l\'api : ' + pathA + ' - Statut retour : ' + res.getStatusCode(), null));

            List<SM002_LigneDeFacture.BAS_Wrapper> listJSONs = (List<SM002_LigneDeFacture.BAS_Wrapper>) System.JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), List<SM002_LigneDeFacture.BAS_Wrapper>.class);

            //Loop Compte
            for (SM002_LigneDeFacture.BAS_Wrapper fgw : listJSONs) {

                if (fgw.client_id instanceOf Id) {

                    String sender;
                    if (fgw.sender == IXOTOKEN) {
                        //IXOTOKEN sert à calculer les alias
                        sender = IXOTOKEN;
                    } else {
                        //les autres senders pour l'instant sont regroupés sans disctinction pour calculer l'acceptation                
                        sender = '';
                    }

                    String accKey = fgw.client_id + fgw.paymentSolution.toUpperCase() + sender;
                    ObjectUtil.debugLog(CLASSNAME, methodName, 'accKey = ' + accKey);
                    mapIdConcatWrapper.put(accKey, fgw);

                    setIdCompte.add(fgw.client_id);

                    if (String.isNotBlank(fgw.distrib_amt) && Decimal.valueOf(fgw.distrib_amt) > 0 && fgw.sender == 'RVD') {
                        mapIdCompte_distribAmt.put(Id.valueOf(fgw.client_id), Decimal.valueOf(fgw.distrib_amt));
                    }

                    //Loop Société
                    if (!fgw.buInformationBilling.isEmpty()) {
                        for (SM002_LigneDeFacture.SocieteWrapper sw : fgw.buInformationBilling) {

                            if (sw.bu_id instanceOf Id) {

                                Map<Id, SM002_LigneDeFacture.SocieteWrapper> mapSocs = mapIdAccMapBUWraps.get(accKey);

                                if (mapSocs == null) {

                                    mapSocs = new Map<Id, SM002_LigneDeFacture.SocieteWrapper> ();
                                    mapSocs.put(sw.bu_id, sw);
                                    mapIdAccMapBUWraps.put(accKey, mapSocs);

                                } else {
                                    mapIdAccMapBUWraps.get(accKey).put(sw.bu_id, sw);
                                }

                                //mapIdSociete_distribAmt.put(sw.bu_id, fgw.distrib_amt);

                                //Loop Magasin
                                if (!sw.magasinInformationBilling.isEmpty()) {

                                    String keySoc = fgw.client_id + sw.bu_id + fgw.paymentSolution.toUpperCase() + sender;
                                    ObjectUtil.debugLog(CLASSNAME, methodName, 'keySoc = ' + keySoc);

                                    for (SM002_LigneDeFacture.MagasinWrapper mw : sw.magasinInformationBilling) {

                                        if (mw.magasin_id instanceOf Id) {

                                            Map<Id, SM002_LigneDeFacture.MagasinWrapper> mapMags = mapIdBuMapMagWraps.get(keySoc);

                                            if (mapMags == null) {

                                                mapMags = new Map<Id, SM002_LigneDeFacture.MagasinWrapper> ();
                                                mapMags.put(mw.magasin_id, mw);
                                                mapIdBuMapMagWraps.put(keySoc, mapMags);

                                            } else {
                                                mapIdBuMapMagWraps.get(keySoc).put(mw.magasin_id, mw);

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            SM015_Balance_Periodique.traitementRetrocomm(mapIdCompte_distribAmt);

            APB002_Data_DPF apb002 = new APB002_Data_DPF(mapIdConcatWrapper, mapIdAccMapBUWraps, mapIdBuMapMagWraps, setIdCompte);
            Database.executeBatch(apb002, 10);

        } else {
            ObjectUtil.debugLog(CLASSNAME, methodName, ' res BODY = ' + res.getBody());
            new ApexDebugLog().createLog(new ApexDebugLog.Error(CLASSNAME, methodName, 'Callout vers l\'api : ' + pathA + ' - Statut retour : ' + res.getStatusCode(), null));
        }

    } else {
        new ApexDebugLog().createLog(new ApexDebugLog.Error(CLASSNAME, methodName, 'Erreur - Callout vers les api acceptation - Statut retour : ' + resKpi.getStatus() + ' - ' + resKpi.getBody(), null));

    }
}
```

the APB002_Data_DPF apb002 looked like this:

```java
global class APB002_Data_DPF implements Database.Batchable<Id>, Database.AllowsCallouts {

    private static final String CLASSNAME = 'APB002_Data_DPF';
    public final String query;
    public static final String PATH = Label.MULESOFT_API_PATH;
    public static final String IXOTOKEN = 'IXO-TOKEN';
    global final Map<String, SM002_LigneDeFacture.BAS_Wrapper> mapIdConcatWrapper;
    global final Map<String, Map<Id, SM002_LigneDeFacture.SocieteWrapper>> mapIdAccMapBUWraps;
    global final Map<String, Map<Id, SM002_LigneDeFacture.MagasinWrapper>> mapIdBuMapMagWraps;
    global final Set<String> setIdComptes;

    public APB002_Data_DPF(Map<String, SM002_LigneDeFacture.BAS_Wrapper> mapWrapper, Map<String, Map<Id, SM002_LigneDeFacture.SocieteWrapper>> mapBUWraps, Map<String, Map<Id, SM002_LigneDeFacture.MagasinWrapper>> mapMagWraps, Set<String> setIdCompte) {

        ObjectUtil.debugLog(CLASSNAME, 'CONSTRUCTOR', ' setIdCompte = ' + setIdCompte);
        mapIdConcatWrapper = mapWrapper;
        mapIdAccMapBUWraps = mapBUWraps;
        mapIdBuMapMagWraps = mapMagWraps;
        setIdComptes = setIdCompte;
    }


    public List<Id> start(Database.BatchableContext context) {

        List<Id> listIds = new List<Id> ();
        ObjectUtil.debugLog(CLASSNAME, 'start', ' setIdComptes = ' + setIdComptes);

        for (Contract c :[Select id FROM Contract WHERE Id IN(SELECT Contract__c FROM Tarification__c WHERE Date_de_Fin__c >= TODAY AND Type_de_facturation__c = 'Par transaction' AND M_thode_de_facturation__c = 'Sur facture' and Compte__c in :setIdComptes)]) {

            listIds.add(c.Id);

        }
        return !listIds.isEmpty() ? listIds : new List<Id> ();
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<Id> scope) {

        String methodName = 'execute';
        ObjectUtil.debugLogBegin(CLASSNAME, methodName, '');

        Map<Id, Contract> mapContrat = new Map<Id, Contract> ([select id, ContractNumber, Account.Id, Groupement__c, ContractTerm, Societe__c, (Select Id, TVA__c, Compte__c, Soci_t__c, Contract__c, Name, Fr_quence__c, Prix__c, Prix_TTC__c, Quantit__c, Prix_Unitaire__c, Date_de_d_but__c, Date_de_Fin__c, TECH_IdGroupement__c, Jour_du_mois_de_facturation__c, Prochaine_date_de_facturation__c, Type_de_facturation__c, Produit2__r.Type_de_facturation__c, Produit2__r.Frequence_de_facturation__c, Produit2__r.Name, Magasin__c, Solution__c, TECH_Nom_Solution__c, Seuil_montant_Acceptation__c, Seuil_volume_Acceptation__c, Variable_PaybyBank__c from Lignes_de_Contrat__r WHERE Date_de_Fin__c >= TODAY AND Type_de_facturation__c = 'Par transaction' AND M_thode_de_facturation__c = 'Sur facture' and Compte__c in :setIdComptes), (Select id, name, Date_Facture__c, Statut__c, Contrat__c, Generation_de_Facture__c, TECH_IdGroupement__c, Perimetre__c FROM Factures__r WHERE CALENDAR_MONTH(Date_Facture__c) = :System.today().month() AND CALENDAR_YEAR(Date_Facture__c) = :System.today().year()) FROM Contract WHERE Id IN :scope]);

        ObjectUtil.debugLog(CLASSNAME, methodName, ' mapContrat = ' + mapContrat);

        SM002_LigneDeFacture.traitementBillingApi(mapContrat, mapIdConcatWrapper, mapIdAccMapBUWraps, mapIdBuMapMagWraps);
    }


    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {

    }
}
```

When I execute it in an anonymous window, each debug logs are duplicated exactly 40 times.
example: this is the debug log from the line "ObjectUtil.debugLog(CLASSNAME, methodName, 'resKpi = ' + resKpi.getBody());"

> 16:30:14.985 (1986249029)|USER_DEBUG|[10]|DEBUG|### >> LOG [SM002_LigneDeFacture] [traitementDPF] [MESSAGE] : resKpi = {"total":64.0}
> 16:30:14.985 (1986259160)|USER_DEBUG|[11]|DEBUG|### >> LOG [SM002_LigneDeFacture] [traitementDPF] [MESSAGE] : resKpi = {"total":64.0}
> 16:30:14.985 (1986268025)|USER_DEBUG|[12]|DEBUG|### >> LOG [SM002_LigneDeFacture] [traitementDPF] [MESSAGE] : resKpi = {"total":64.0}
> 16:30:14.985 (1986277199)|USER_DEBUG|[13]|DEBUG|### >> LOG [SM002_LigneDeFacture] [traitementDPF] [MESSAGE] : resKpi = {"total":64.0}
> ...
> 16:30:14.985 (1986632953)|USER_DEBUG|[48]|DEBUG|### >> LOG [SM002_LigneDeFacture] [traitementDPF] [MESSAGE] : resKpi = {"total":64.0}
> 16:30:14.985 (1986641475)|USER_DEBUG|[49]|DEBUG|### >> LOG [SM002_LigneDeFacture] [traitementDPF] [MESSAGE] : resKpi = {"total":64.0}
> 16:30:14.985 (1986650131)|USER_DEBUG|[50]|DEBUG|### >> LOG [SM002_LigneDeFacture] [traitementDPF] [MESSAGE] : resKpi = {"total":64.0}

The line is repeated 40 times in a row which trigger limits like flow limits "Number of Iterations Exceeded"

Does it means this code is executed 40 times? because it doesn't look like it.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: I've taken the liberty of removing most of the repeated messages in the log (since the only thing that's different is the reported line number, and that just increments by 1 each time).

Comment: Sure no problem, thanks.

Comment: the debug log means that the static method `initTraitementBillingApi` is being executed 40 times. You need to see who invokes this

Comment: Hi @cropredy, as mentionned, i executed this method in a anonymous window.  What is even more weird is that i just realized ALL my debug logs present this issue, no matter what i do in salesforce the system debug line a duplicated 40 times. Has anyone ever seen this behaviour?

Comment: are you saying that if execute anonymous just has one line `system.debug('foo')` that you will see that appear 40 times?

Comment: If i execute initTraitementBillingApi() only once in anonymous, i see all the system.debug 40 times.